# How to enter string to sort container?

Tags: c++, sorting, c++11, containers

I have the following strings:
1465883175.476876 RX 0x03 0x00000000

1465883175.606049 RX 0x00 0x00000000

1465883175.783562 RX 0x02 0x00000000

1465883175.906900 RX 0x03 0x00000000

1465883176.051490 RX 0x00 0x00000000

1465883176.201903 RX 0x03 0x00000000

How can I enter them to a container which will sort them according to the first data which is a double type (c++)?

I have to do it in the most effective way.

I consider to use std::set container, but in this container no two elements in the container can have equivalent key. In ny case the strings might contain the same number.

Comment: As the pop out box states on the right hand of when you Ask a Question: *Provide details. Share your research.*

Comment: You could put them in a `std::vector` as strings and use [`std::sort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) with your own comparison function that parses the double and compares them. Or you could use a struct with the parsed fields and put those in a vector, so you don't have to parse the double for each comparison.

Comment: @ Karsten Koop- what about priority queue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>

int main() {
  std::vector<std::string> s{
   "1465883175.476876 RX 0x03 0x00000000"
  ,"1465883175.606049 RX 0x00 0x00000000"
  ,"1465883175.783562 RX 0x02 0x00000000"
  ,"1465883175.906900 RX 0x03 0x00000000"
  ,"1465883176.051490 RX 0x00 0x00000000"
  ,"1465883176.201903 RX 0x03 0x00000000"};

  auto cmp = [](const std::string &f, const std::string &s) {
    double n1 = 0.0;
    size_t processed1{0};
    auto sub_str1 = f.substr(0, f.find(" "));
    try {
      n1 = std::stod(sub_str1, &processed1);
      if (processed1 != sub_str1.size()) {
        // TODO
      }
    } catch (std::invalid_argument ia) {
      // TODO
    } catch (std::out_of_range oor) {
      // TODO
    }

    double n2 = 0.0;
    size_t processed2{0};
    auto sub_str2 = s.substr(0, s.find(" "));
    try {
      n2 = std::stod(sub_str2, &processed2);
      if (processed2 != sub_str2.size()) {
        // TODO
      }
    } catch (std::invalid_argument ia) {
      // TODO
    } catch (std::out_of_range oor) {
      // TODO
    }

    return n1 > n2;
  };

  std::priority_queue<std::string, std::vector<std::string>, decltype(cmp)> q(cmp);

  for (const auto &c : s) {
    q.push(c);
  }
  while (!q.empty()) {
    std::cout << q.top() << "\n";
    q.pop();
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: The priority queue shouldn't have a key for soritinh? I mean can't I give it the key, and it should inest it automaticallywith sorting?

Comment: The priority queue need a comparative function(cmp on the code), a priority_queue is similar to managing a heap in some random access container, with the benefit of not being able to accidentally invalidate the heap...
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue

Comment: Ok, so is there any container which can get a dpecific key and sort according this key (in this case the number)?

Comment: Plus it it possible to upgrade it to sort 2 vectors, ot I have to append them to one vector?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code with c++11 compiler support(you need improve this):

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  std::vector<std::string> s{
   "1465883175.476876 RX 0x03 0x00000000"
  ,"1465883175.606049 RX 0x00 0x00000000"
  ,"1465883175.783562 RX 0x02 0x00000000"
  ,"1465883175.906900 RX 0x03 0x00000000"
  ,"1465883176.051490 RX 0x00 0x00000000"
  ,"1465883176.201903 RX 0x03 0x00000000"};

  std::sort(s.begin(), s.end(), [](const std::string &f, const std::string &s){
    double n1 = 0.0;
    size_t processed1{0};
    auto sub_str1 = f.substr(0, f.find(" "));
    try {
      n1 = std::stod(sub_str1, &processed1);
      if (processed1 != sub_str1.size()) {
        // TODO
      }
    } catch (std::invalid_argument ia) {
      // TODO
    } catch (std::out_of_range oor) {
      // TODO
    }

    double n2 = 0.0;
    size_t processed2{0};
    auto sub_str2 = s.substr(0, s.find(" "));
    try {
      n2 = std::stod(sub_str2, &processed2);
      if (processed2 != sub_str2.size()) {
        // TODO
      }
    } catch (std::invalid_argument ia) {
      // TODO
    } catch (std::out_of_range oor) {
      // TODO
    }

    return n1 < n2;
  });
  for (const auto &c : s) {
    std::cout << c << "\n";
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: The purpose is it to insert the elements of the vector to a container which insert them by sorting.

Comment: The relevant is the lamda, so use this in a priority queue. see an example.